# Copy & Transpose Values from 1 Workbook to Another

Tags: vba, excel, paste

```
Sub LoopThroughDecTab()
Dim MyFile As String
Dim erow
Dim FilePath As String

FilePath = "C:"
MyFile = Dir(FilePath)


Do While Len(MyFile) > 0
If MyFile = "Dec Tab Macro.xlsm" Then
Exit Sub
End If

Workbooks.Open (FilePath & MyFile)
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Declaration Analysis (Source)").Activate
Range("H9:H21").Copy
ActiveWorkbook.Close False
```

'Getting Runtime error PasteSpecialMethod of Range Failed on following line'

```
ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(erow, 1), Cells(erow, 7)).PasteSpecial.Range Transpose:=True 

MyFile = Dir

Loop

End Sub
```

I have files in a folder, the code loops through the files copies values and then I want those values Transposed into the Active MasterSheet. There are 7 values that need to be pasted, and then it should open the next workbook in folder and repeat the process.

Comment: Possible the copy is being cancelled because you close the workbook right away, look here to see an example of looping through a folder of workbooks...[Loop Through Folder](http://www.xlorate.com/vba-examples.html#Loop Through Folder)

Comment: Thanks, that doesnt seem to be the issue. I see that it copies the values and attempts to paste it, it just wont paste it. I updated my code based on the link u provided, get the same error.

Comment: Try pasting before you close the workbook

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you posted your complete code, and simply interjected the 'non-code' message to tell us where your error was, give this a try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub LoopThroughDecTab()
Dim MyFile As String
Dim erow
Dim FilePath As String
Dim DestWB as Workbook
Dim SourceWB as Workbook

'this way we know the one where the code is running and the destination for our copies
set DestWB = ThisWorkbook 

FilePath = "C:"
MyFile = Dir(FilePath)

Do While Len(MyFile) > 0
    If MyFile = "Dec Tab Macro.xlsm" Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Set SourceWB = Workbooks.Open (FilePath & MyFile)
    SourceWB.Worksheets("Declaration Analysis (Source)").Range("H9:H21").Copy
'Move the close to AFTER you do the paste
'NOTE: You may have to make a change here:
    DestWB.Range(Cells(erow, 1), Cells(erow, 7)).PasteSpecial.Range Transpose:=True 
    SourceWB.Close False
    MyFile = Dir
Loop

End Sub
```

If you open two workbooks (A & B) in Excel, copy some cells from A, close A, then try to paste into B, you'll have nothing left to paste - closing A clears the clipboard buffer. I believe the same thing is happening here.

### Important Notes:

1. I've removed all references to `ActiveWorkbook` - I believe that I've gotten it correct, but I always get a bit lost when using `Active*`, so I avoid it at all cost. (There are a *very* few situations where it's the only way to get things done, this isn't one of them.) If I've messed up your source & destinations for the copy, simply reverse the `Set` statements so you're using them the other way.
2. I'm not sure where `erow` and `FilePath` are getting set, so I'm assuming this wasn't the complete code. The assumption is that they'll still get set somehow.
3. I've not used the copy/transpose function, so you may well need to include [Excel Developers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29630777/2344413)'s adjustments, as well.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to understand what's the problem without seeing what are you copying, but you can try:

```
ActiveSheet.Cells(erow, 1).PasteSpecial Transpose:=True
```

Comment: Thanks for assisting. I tried that but got same error. Trying to copy 7 values and paste it in one row, then when it loops it will copy the 7 values fromt the next sheet and paste it directly under the previous values in my master sheet.

Comment: In your code I've read `Range("H9:H21").Copy` So I've tought that you are copying from a row to transpose in a column. Isn't so?

Answer (score 0):

```
set CopyFromRange = Range("H9:H21")
set CopyToRange = ActiveSheet.Cells(erow,1).Resize(1,13)
CopyToRange.Value = Application.Transpose(CopyFromRange.Value)
```